# How Does Vertex Labeling Affect Chains?

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory

I am working through Hatcher on my own and have gotten near the end of Chapter 2.  One thing that I remain confused about are the powers of -1 that are inserted in the formulas for boundaries and other chains which are defined as formal sums.  (See Hatcher p.104 for the first mention of such signs.)

Obviously, these signs are critical in much of what follows since they determine when chains sum to zero.

Here's my problem: The labels/subscripts of the vertices are arbitrary, and thus the signs in the sums are arbitrary.  Consequently, how can we be sure the signs are "right" and, for example, sum to zero for cycles?

Hatcher does not not go into this question.  So, is there some "natural" way of labeling vertices that makes it all work?  Or, is there a set of rules for labeling that always works as long as such rules are followed?

Also, how do we know a "correct" labeling system will always exist as we move to higher dimensions and more complex shapes?

Thanks for any comments or observations.

Comment: You’re essentially assigning orientations to these objects.The short answer is that it doesn’t matter how these orientations are assigned as long as they’re reflected correctly in the boundary operators—there’s no single “right” assignment. It would be an instructive exercise to work through a few examples and see that different orientation assignments don’t actually change which chains sum to zero (or even prove that this is true in general).

Comment: Another way to look at is is that you’re choosing bases for various vector spaces when you assign the pluses and minuses. Changing bases of the domain and codomain of a linear map doesn’t change its kernel, but it does affect the °representation° of the map and its kernel as coefficient matrices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, it doesn’t really matter where the pluses and minuses go. Just as the labels are arbitrary, so is the assignment of orientations—there’s no “right” assignment and it all works out. The orientations need not even be consistent among different-dimension chains within the complex. In fact, it might not even be possible to make such a globally consistent assignment.

Looking at it from a linear-algebraic point of view, when you assign orientations, you’re choosing a basis for the vector space of chains. The chains that sum to zero are the kernel of the boundary map $\partial_k:C_{k+1}\to C_k$ from $(k+1)$-chains to $k$-chains. This kernel is independent of the choice of bases: changing bases only changes its representation and that of the boundary operator as coefficient matrices.

Let’s look at what happens with a graph. The boundary operator $\partial:C_1\to C_0$ can be represented as a matrix with rows indexed by node and columns indexed by edge. Relabeling the edges permutes the columns of this matrix, which of course has no effect whatsoever on its kernel and image. Relabeling nodes permutes the rows, which is the same as permuting the coordinates of the tuples that represent chains. So far, so good: the labels are arbitrary and have no effect on which chains sum to zero.

Now, what happens if you reverse the orientation of edge $j$? This amounts to negating the $j$th column of the matrix $\partial$ or equivalently, of choosing $-\mathbf v_j$ instead of $\mathbf v_j$ as the $j$th basis vector of $C_1$. This simply negates the $j$th coordinate of the tuples that represent $1$-chains, i.e., it changes their representation as coordinate tuples, but not the vectors that those tuples represent.

One other thing to look at is the effect of changing the orientation of an elementary $k$-chain on $\partial_k$ when $k\gt0$. In matrix terms, doing so negates a *row* of the matrix of $\partial_k$. This leaves the row space of this matrix unchanged, and since its kernel is the orthogonal complement of its row space, that, too, is unaffected.

To take a relatively simple example, consider the directed graph with edges $1\to2$, $2\to3$, $1\to3$, $2\to4$ and $3\to4$. The corresponding boundary operator matrix is $$\partial = \begin{bmatrix} -1&0&-1&0&0 \\ 1&-1&0&-1&0 \\ 0&1&1&0&-1 \\ 0&0&0&1&1 \end{bmatrix}.$$ Its kernel is easily found via standard techniques to be spanned by $(-1,-1,1,0,0)^T$ and $(0,1,0,-1,1)^T$ (these are the two smaller loops in the graph), so every linear combination of these two chains sums to zero. For instance, the larger outer loop is the sum of these two loops. Now reverse the orientation of the second edge and recompute: the kernel is now spanned by $(-1,1,1,0,0)^T$ and $(0,-1,0,-1,1)^T$. Comparing these two bases, we find that the only difference is that the second component of the coordinate vectors has been negated, exactly as expected.

Comment: I am not accustomed to looking at it from such a linear algebra approach, but I can see how that clarifies things. In your example, the directed graph must be a 5x1 vector (right?).  What is that vector specifically?  I can piece a lot of the logic together from your explanation and your example, but a reference would be nice if you have one.

Comment: @MPitts I was first exposed to this approach in vol. 2 of Bamberg & Sternberg’s *A Course In Mathematics For Students of Physics*, which I’m pretty sure you can find online these days. I’m sure there are other, better texts that do this, too, but I’m not really well-versed in what textbooks are around these days. B&S introduce this vector-space approach in the context of electrical networks, then develop the exterior differential calculus and Maxwell’s equations as continuous analogues of discrete networks. Caveat: this book has a lot of errors, many fewer in vol. 2 than vol. 1, though.

Comment: @MPitts You might also look for algebraic topology texts, which often include this approach.